# How to reverse a sentence in C and Perl

Tags: c, perl

If the sentence is 
"My name is Jack"
then the output should be
"Jack is name My".

I did a program using `strtok()` to separate the words and then push them onto a stack,
popping them and concatenating.

Is there any other, more efficient way than this?
Is it easier to do in Perl?

Comment: It is far simpler in Perl than it is in C.

Answer (score 8):

Whether it is more efficient or not will be something you can test but in Perl you could do something along the lines of:

```
my $reversed = join( " ", reverse( split( / /, $string ) ) );
```

Answer (score 5):

Perl makes this kind of text manipulation very easy, you can even test this easily on the shell:

```
echo "run as fast as you can" | perl -lne 'print join $",reverse split /\W+/'
```

or:

```
echo "all your bases are belong to us" | perl -lne '@a=reverse /\w+/g;print "@a"'
```

Comment: FYI, the "base" is singular ;)

Answer (score 4):

The strategy for C could be this:

1) Reverse the characters of the string.  This results in the words being the right general position, albeit backward.
2) Reverse the characters of each word in the string.

We will need one function to reverse characters in a buffer:

```
/*
 * Reverse characters in a buffer.
 * 
 * If provided "My name is Jack", modifies the input to become
 * "kcaJ si eman yM".
 */
void reverse_chars(char * buf, int cch_len)
{
    char * front = buf, *back = buf + cch_len - 1;

    while (front < back)
    {
        char tmp = *front;
        *front = *back;
        *back = tmp;
        front ++;
        back --;
    }
}
```

For the purpose of breaking the input buffer into words, a function which returns the number of non-space characters in the buffer.  (strtok() modifies the buffer and is harder to use in-place)

```
int word_len(char *input)
{
    char * p = input;

    while (*p && !isspace(*p))
        p++;

    return p - input;
}
```

Finally, we will need a function which uses those two helpers to achieve the strategy described in the first paragraph.

```
/*
 * Reverse words in a buffer.
 *
 * Given the input "My name is Jack", modifies the input to become
 * "Jack is name My"
 */
void reverse_words(char *input)
{
     int cch_len = strlen(input);

     /* Part 1: Reverse the string characters. */
     reverse_chars(input, cch_len);

     char * p = input;

     /* Part 2: Loop over one word at a time. */
     while (*p)
     {
         /* Skip leading spaces */
         while (*p && isspace(*p))
             p++;

         if (*p)
         {
             /* Advance one complete word. */
             int cch_word = word_len(p);
             reverse_chars(p, cch_word);
             p += cch_word;
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've gotten a couple of versions in C, but they strike me as a bit more verbose than is probably really necessary. Absent a reason to do otherwise, I'd consider something like this:

```
#define MAX 32

char *words[MAX];
char word[256];
int pos = 0;

for (pos=0; pos<MAX && scanf("%255s", word); pos++)
    words[pos] = strdup(word);

while (--pos >= 0)
  printf("%s ", words[pos]);
```

One possible "intermediate" level between C and Perl would be C++:

```
std::istringstream input("My name is Jack");
std::vector<std::string> words((std::istream_iterator<std::string>(input)),
                               std::istream_iterator<std::string>());

std::copy(words.rbegin(), words.rend(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
```

Comment: strdup calls should be matched with calls to free

Comment: @frankc: yes, ultimately they need to be, of course. Likeiwise, you also need to `#include` the proper headers, add a function header for `main`, etc. This doesn't attempt to include any of the above, just the parts directly related to reversing the words.

Answer (score 2):

Some fun with a little help from regexp and perl special variables :)

```
$_ = "My name is Jack";
unshift @_, "$1 " while /(\w+)/g;
print @_;
```

**EDIT**

And a killer (by now):

```
$,=' ';print reverse /\w+/g;
```

Little explanation: $, is [special variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for print output separator. Of course you can do it in shorter way without this special var:

```
print reverse /\w+ ?/g;
```

but the result might be not as satisfactiry as example above.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a C idea that uses a little recursion to do the stacking for you:

```
void rev(char * x){
  char * p;
  if(p = strchr(x, ' ')){
    rev(p+1);
    printf("%.*s ", p-x, x);
  }
  else{
    printf("%s ", x);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`reverse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html):

```
my @words = split / /, $sentence;
my $newSentence = join(' ', reverse @words);
```

Comment: The '`//`' should probably be '`/ /`', should it not?  When I test it on the sample data, I get '`e m a n   y m   s i   k c a J`'. (And thank you, Markdown, for ignoring my careful spacing in the code!).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Of course, my mistake. Was thinking of `split` (with no arguments).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a lot easier to do in Perl, but...

```
char *strrtok(char *str, const char *delim)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = strlen(str) - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        // Sets the furthest set of contiguous delimiters to null characters
        if (strchr(delim, str[i]))
        {
            j = i + 1;

            while (strchr(delim, str[i]) && i >= 0)
            {
                str[i] = '\0';
                i--;
            }

            return &(str[j]);
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```

This should work similarly to `strtok()` in reverse, but you continue to pass the pointer to the original string location rather than passing NULL after the first call. Also, you should get empty strings for start and end cases.

Answer (score 0):

C version:

```
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char s[] = "My name is Jack";
char t[100];
int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

for(i = strlen(s) - 1 ; i >= 0 ;i--)
{
    if(s[i] == ' ' || i == 0)
    {
        j = i == 0 ?  i : i + 1;
        for(j = j; s[j] != '\0'; j++) t[k++] = s[j];
        t[k++] = ' ';
        s[i] = '\0';
    }
}
t[k] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", t);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

C example

```
char * srtrev (char * str) {

       int l = strlen(str);
       char * rev;
       while(l != 0)
       {
         rev += str[ --l];
       }
        return rev;
}
```

Comment: That reverses characters, not words.

Comment: ```rev``` is never initialized.